# The HTML content inside JEditorPane has blue background in Java

Tags: java, html, css, jeditorpane

I have this Desktop email client program that I'm currently working on in Java and I want to show the incoming mail content inside a JEditorPane.
I've created an HTMLEditorKit and set it as an editor kit for the JEditorPane control like this:
`editorPane.setEditorKit(htmlEditorKit);`
And for some messages, it works fine but for some others, it shows its background as a blue-colored one. I tried to add a stylesheet rule to the kit, but it didn't work.
What could have been the problem?
Any comments will be welcome.

EDIT:

```
JEditorPane txtContent = new JEditorPane();
txtContent.setEditable(false);
txtContent.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
txtContent.setBounds(316, 110, 598, 545);
kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
txtContent.setEditorKit(kit);
HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument)kit.createDefaultDocument();
txtContent.setDocument(doc);
txtContent.setText("HTML content here.....");
```

When I put "HTML content here....." part inside an html file with Notepad, it shows the right thing.

But when I put the exact same content inside the JEditorPane like the above, it shows different styling(blue background).

Comment: Where is your code? Post your code in the question, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? **Complete** – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem. That means a small example that can be compiler and run together with a small sample email that cuase the problem.

Comment: Oh, okay you're right. I'm going to do that but I have to do some work for extracting the required code parts.

Comment: I've edited some parts. But because of my low rep, couldn't add pictures. The code is not "self-compilable", but there is nothing more special to be added.